# Solving an ODE with a Time-Dependent Variable

Tags: python, math, ode

For the 2 systems of ODE, I am using RK4 to solve. From `0 <= t <= 30`, `b` is a constant. But at `t >= 30`, `b` is a time-dependent variable where `b = 1.2 * exp(-0.5 * (t - 30))`.

I tried to implement it, but there's an error saying `setting an array element with a sequence`. How should I implement the time-variable?

```py
a = 0.05
b = 1.2


def fA(A, F, t):
    return -A + a * F + A**2 * F


def fF(A, F, t):
    return b - a * F - A**2 * F


h = 0.1
t = np.arange(0, 100 + h, h)
A = np.zeros(t.shape)
F = np.zeros(t.shape)
A[0] = 1
F[0] = 1

for i in range(len(t) - 1):
    if t[i] >= 30:
        b = 1.2 * np.exp(-0.5 * (t - 30))  # <-- error here

    kA1 = fA(A[i], F[i], t[i])
    kF1 = fF(A[i], F[i], t[i])

    kA2 = fA(A[i] + h * kA1 / 2, F[i] + h * kF1 / 2, t[i] + h / 2)
    kF2 = fF(A[i] + h * kA1 / 2, F[i] + h * kF1 / 2, t[i] + h / 2)

    kA3 = fA(A[i] + h * kA2 / 2, F[i] + h * kF2 / 2, t[i] + h / 2)
    kF3 = fF(A[i] + h * kA2 / 2, F[i] + h * kF2 / 2, t[i] + h / 2)

    kA4 = fA(A[i] + h * kA3 / 2, F[i] + h * kF3 / 2, t[i] + h / 2)
    kF4 = fF(A[i] + h * kA3 / 2, F[i] + h * kF3 / 2, t[i] + h / 2)

    kA = (kA1 + 2 * kA2 + 2 * kA3 + kA4) / 6
    kF = (kF1 + 2 * kF2 + 2 * kF3 + kF4) / 6

    A[i + 1] = A[i] + h * kA
    F[i + 1] = F[i] + h * kF

plt.plot(t, A)
plt.plot(t, F)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first code I use the integrator developed in scipy.integrate.solve_ivp from scipy.
Code 1.

```python
##########################################
# AUTHOR  : CARLOS DUARDO DA SILVA LIMA  #
# DATE    : 03/12/2022                   #
# LANGUAGE: python                       #
# IDE     : GOOGLE COLAB                 #
# CODE 1  :                              #
##########################################

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint, solve_ivp

# Ordinary Differential Equations
a = 0.05
b = 1.20

def B(t):
  return 1.2*np.exp(-0.5*(t-30))

def f(t,r):
  x,y=r
  if t>=0 and t<=30:
    ode1 = -x+a*y+x**2*y
    ode2 = b-a*y-x**2*y
    s = np.array([ode1,ode2])
    return s
  elif t>30:
    b_ = B(t)
    ode1 = -x+a*y+x**2*y
    ode2 = b_-a*y-x**2*y
    s = np.array([ode1,ode2])
    return s

# Time t0<=t<=tf
ti = 0.0
tf = 100.0
t  = np.array([ti,tf])

# Initial conditions
x0 = 1.0
y0 = 1.0
r0 = np.array([x0,y0])

# Solving the set of ordinary differential equations (Initial Value Problem)
#sol = solve_ivp(f, t_span = t, y0 = r0,method='Radau', rtol=1E-09, atol=1e-09)
#sol = solve_ivp(f, t_span = t, y0 = r0,method='DOP853', rtol=1E-09, atol=1e-09)
#sol = solve_ivp(f, t_span = t, y0 = r0,method='RK23', rtol=1E-09, atol=1e-09)
sol = solve_ivp(f, t_span = t, y0 = r0,method='RK45', rtol=1E-09, atol=1e-09)

t_= sol.t
x = sol.y[0, :]
y = sol.y[1, :]

# graphic
plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
plt.style.use('dark_background')
plt.title('scipy.integrate.solve_ivp - RK45')
plt.plot(t_,x,'y.',t_,y,'g.')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('x, y')
plt.legend(['x', 'y'], shadow=True)
plt.grid(lw = 0.95,color = 'white',linestyle = '--')
plt.show()
```

[Figure 1: Output graph using scipy.integrate.solve_ivp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPQWT.png)

In the second code I try to solve the problem following his reasoning, creating the fourth order Runge-Kutta method in the initial value problem. Heads up! The initial conditions for x0 and y0 were informed and I use them in both codes (code 1 and code 2), **x0 = 1.0** and **y0 = 1.0**.

```python
##########################################
# AUTHOR  : CARLOS DUARDO DA SILVA LIMA  #
# DATE    : 03/12/2022                   #
# LANGUAGE: python                       #
# IDE     : GOOGLE COLAB                 #
# CODE 2  :                              #
##########################################

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint, solve_ivp

# Ordinary Differential Equations
a = 0.05
b = 1.20

def B(t):
  return 1.2*np.exp(-0.5*(t-30))

def f(t,x,y):
  if t>=0 and t<=30:
    ode1 = -x+a*y+x**2*y
    ode2 = b-a*y-x**2*y
    s = np.array([ode1,ode2])
    return s
  elif t>30:
    b_ = B(t)
    ode1 = -x+a*y+x**2*y
    ode2 = b_-a*y-x**2*y
    s = np.array([ode1,ode2])
    return s

# Initial conditions
ti = 0.0
x0 = 1.0
y0 = 1.0
N = 1000000
h = 1E-4 # Step

t = np.zeros(N)
x = np.zeros(N)
y = np.zeros(N)
t[0] = ti
x[0] = x0
y[0] = y0

for i in range(0,N-1,1):
  k11 = h*f(t[i],x[i],y[i])[0]
  k12 = h*f(t[i],x[i],y[i])[1]

  k21 = h*f(t[i]+(h/2),x[i]+(k11/2),y[i]+(k12/2))[0]
  k22 = h*f(t[i]+(h/2),x[i]+(k11/2),y[i]+(k12/2))[1]

  k31 = h*f(t[i]+(h/2),x[i]+(k21/2),y[i]+(k22/2))[0]
  k32 = h*f(t[i]+(h/2),x[i]+(k21/2),y[i]+(k22/2))[1]

  k41 = h*f(t[i]+h,x[i]+k31,y[i]+k32)[0]
  k42 = h*f(t[i]+h,x[i]+k31,y[i]+k32)[1]

  x[i+1] = x[i] + ((k11+2*(k21+k31)+k41)/6)
  y[i+1] = y[i] + ((k12+2*(k22+k32)+k42)/6)
  t[i+1] = t[i] + h 

# graphic
t_ = t
plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
plt.style.use('dark_background')
plt.title('4-Order Runge-Kutta')
plt.plot(t_,x,'r.',t_,y,'b.')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('x, y')
plt.legend(['x', 'y'], shadow=True)
plt.grid(lw = 0.95,color = 'white',linestyle = '--')
plt.show()
```

[Figure 2: Output graph 4-Order Runge-Kutta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE7wm.png)

In case you don't want to be limited only between 0<=t<=30, we can use a simple logic, like.

```python
def f(t,r):
  x,y=r
  if t>=30:
    b_ = B(t)
    ode1 = -x+a*y+x**2*y
    ode2 = b_-a*y-x**2*y
    s = np.array([ode1,ode2])
    return s
  else:
    ode1 = -x+a*y+x**2*y
    ode2 = b-a*y-x**2*y
    s = np.array([ode1,ode2])
    return s
```

You can apply them to both of the above codes by replacing the function f, bounded between 0<=t<=30 and t>30. One last note! I replaced variables A and F with x and y. Up until :).

Comment: Just a tip: it is not usual to have headers giving credits to ourselves in the snippets we post. Everyone here can see it was posted by you, so there is no point in doing that. Please, spend some time reading ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). And finally, we can see the code is in Python. That's why we assign tags to questions.